# Proof of non-reflexivity of $l^\infty$ by finding a bounded sequence such that it contains no weakly convergent subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, reflexive-space

I want to prove that $l^\infty$ is not reflexive, however I do not want to check why canonical inclusion of $l^\infty$ to $(l^{\infty})^{**}$ is not an isometric isomorphism. I know that if a normed space is reflexive then every bounded sequence of its elements has weakly convergent subsequence. In the case of $l^\infty$ which sequence should I take to break this property?

Thank you.

Comment: The general counterexample I know for $l^\infty$ is $\{x_n\}$ such that the $n^{th}$ term of $x_n$ is $1$ and the rest are $0$.  I think this sequence can work here, too

Comment: You could show that $l^{\infty} $ isn't reflexive through a different idea : it is the dual of $l^1$, and, because a Banach space is reflexive if and only if the dual of this space is reflexive you can just proove that $l^1$ isn't reflexive. Thus, it is possible to finish this by showing that given a separable reflexive Banach space, its dual is separable.

Comment: @Ryan I thought about it too. Choosing functionals $f_i(x)=x_i$ and applying to this sequence we can show that if there is a convergent subsequence, then it must converge to $0$. However I didn't come up with example of functional such that $f(e_n)$ wouldn't converge to $0$. If we find such a functional, the problem is solved. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider the Cesaro limit on the subspace where it is defined and use Hahn Banach to get your result.

Comment: @Paul I like your first idea for the proof. Returning to the sequence, what do you mean by Cesaro limit?

Comment: The limit of the mean of the element of the sequence between $k=1$ and $k=n $ when $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: The Cesaro limit doesn't work, sorry...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be a [Banach limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit). Define $x_n$ as
$$
x_n = (1,0,1,0,\dots, 1,0,0, \dots) = \sum_{k=1}^n e_{2n-1}.
$$
Since only finitely many entries of $x_n$ are non-zero, $\phi(x_n) = 0$. The sequence $(x_n)$ converges weak-star in $l^\infty=(l^1)^*$ to the periodic sequence $x=(1,0,1,0,\dots)$. Now due to the properties of the Banach limit, $\phi(x)=\frac12 \ne \phi(0) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \phi(x_n)$. Hence $x_n \not\rightharpoonup x$ in $l^\infty$, and there can be no other weak limit, as the weak-star limit $x$ is uniquely determined.